# detecting input in dynamically generated input

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, loops

My code dynamically generates a series of input fields. Each row of fields belongs to one database record and I use php's dynamic array notation ('[]') to capture the values. 
Then at the input field i want to show the price input value that have been multiplied by total number of item that the data is generated from database.

I used javascript that placed inside foreach looping to detect the input and multiply it, but it only works for the first field, at the second field the multiplied value shown on the first field too.

this is the code structure :

```
<?php foreach ($barang->result_array() as $row): ?>
<tr>
    <td><?php echo $row['nmbr']; ?> </td>
    <td><?php echo $row['jumlah']?> </td>
    <td><input id="pnwrn" type="text" name="pnwrn[]"  value="" />

    <input type="hidden" name="id_barang[]" value="<?php echo $row['id_barang']?>" /> 
    <input type="hidden" name="jumlah[]" value="<?php echo $row['jumlah']?>" /> </td>
    <td><div id="output"><script type="text/javascript">
        var harga = <?php echo $row['jumlah']; ?>;
        $('input').bind('input propertychange', function () {
            $('#output').html($(this).val()*harga);
        });
    </script>
    </div></td>
</tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

I tried to make the output show the multiply value in each row but have no result yet..can someone tell me where i make my mistake?
thanks ~

Comment: IDs must be unique on document context, use class instead and target specific row's element using any transversal DOM method. BTW, you shouldn't bind event in PHP loop. Here, on each iteration, you are rebinding event for already created input elements

Comment: I also doubt that you can actually define `harga` several times on a global level. That will just override the variable every time and using `var` multiple times should also throw an error, I guess.

Comment: when i insert a value into `pnwrn` on a row the output only shown at the first field and when i change next row, the output on the first field also changed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several issues that others have pointed out in the comments.

The reason why every value on the page is changing is because you are using an id for the output div instead of a class and your jQuery change handler is saying: "get everything with an id of output and put this new html in it."  Aside from that, it's not valid to use an id more than once on a page.  So, **change both the output and pnwrn to classes**.

To make it simple to get the corresponding 'harga' value later, you can just store it as data on the input.

```
<?php foreach ($barang->result_array() as $row): ?>
<tr>
    <td><?php echo $row['nmbr']; ?> </td>
    <td><?php echo $row['jumlah']?> </td>
    <td><input class="pnwrn" type="text" name="pnwrn[]"  value="" data-harga="<?php echo $row['jumlah']?>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="id_barang[]" value="<?php echo $row['id_barang']?>" /> 
    <input type="hidden" name="jumlah[]" value="<?php echo $row['jumlah']?>" /> </td>
    <td><div class="output"></div></td>
</tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

The second issue is that you are writing a separate handler in every single table row.  This is not only inefficient, it's hard to read the output and completely unnecessary. You just want your script once on the page so **don't include it in your loop**.  To get to the corresponding values for your calculation, you can just retrieve the data value stored on the input.  Then, you can use DOM traversal to find the corresponding output div.  In this case, go up to the nearest ancestor row, then find its descendent element with the output class. Also, unless you are using a really old version of jQuery, use the on method instead of the deprecated bind.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('input').on('change', function () {
  var harga = parseInt($(this).data('harga'));
  $('this').parents('tr').find('.output').html($(this).val()*harga);
});
</script>
```